# ORACLE SQL - Categorizing records based on logic

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the best way categorize records based on logic?

For example, from this table:

```
ID House  Farm
1  (null) (null)
```

I would like to output:

```
ID Missing
1  House
1  Farm
```

Aside from the obvious UNION all below, is there a better way?  Maybe a case when?  UNION ALL will not be easily flexible when dealing with a bigger number of conditions.

```
select ID, 'House' as Missing from table where house is null
union all 
select ID, 'Farm' as Missing from table where farm is null
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?  In 11g, you could potentially use the `UNPIVOT` operator.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't know if it's more efficient than `UNION ALL`, another option is to use `UNPIVOT` depending on the version of Oracle you are using:

```
SELECT ID, Missing
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM   YourTable
    UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (IsMissing FOR Missing IN (House as 'House', Farm as 'Farm'))
  ) t
WHERE IsMissing IS NULL
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf77d/2).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the result using UNPIVOT. Check the links [pivot and unpivot queries in 11g](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506), [PIVOT and UNPIVOT Operators in Oracle Database 11g Release 1](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) for more details.

```
SELECT 
  ID, MISSING
FROM  
(
    SELECT  ID, NVL(HOUSE, 1) HOUSE, NVL(FARM, 1) FARM FROM YourTable
 )x
UNPIVOT (
 DCol
 FOR MISSING
 IN  (HOUSE, FARM) 
);
```

or

```
SELECT 
  ID, MISSING
FROM YourTable 
UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (
DCol
FOR MISSING
IN  (HOUSE, FARM) 
);
```